# How simulate time with tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

I should realize a simulator of a supermarket. In this simulator, moving circles represents the people that are moving in the supermarket. To implement the simulator I choose to use Tkinter. I would know if there is a way to implement the time. More precisely I need to create a couple (position, time). I already know that the method after doesn't help me in this case. So how can I solve this problem? I hope I am clear, and I report in the following the code I wrote. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
animation = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(animation, width=800, height=700)
canvas.pack()
x1 = 250
y1 = 110
a1 = 260
b1 = 120
x1_vel = 0
y1_vel = 5

coord1 = [x1, y1, a1, b1]
circle1 = canvas.create_oval(coord1, fill="blue")
def move1():
     global x1
     global y1
     global x1_vel
     global y1_vel
     if y1 > 550:
          y1_vel = 0
          x1_vel = - 5
     if x1 < 180:
          y1_vel = - 5
          x1_vel = 0
     if y1 < 90:
          x1_vel = 5
          y1_vel = 0
     if x1 > 430:
          y1_vel = 5
          x1_vel = 0
     if y1 > 570:
          x1_vel = -5
          y1_vel = 0
     if x1 < 90:
          x1_vel = 0
     canvas.move(circle1, x1_vel, y1_vel)
     coordinates = canvas.coords(circle1)
     x1 = coordinates[0]
     y1 = coordinates[1]
     animation.after(33, move1)

move1()
animation.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***a way to implement the time***: Rephrase or explain in more detail.

Comment: I need to associate a time instant to every position of the circle. Is it more clear now?

Comment: You want to move every circle depending on a individual time value per circle?

Comment: Yes, I want this behavior

Comment: _"I already know that the method after doesn't help me in this case. "_ - how do you know that? It's also not clear what you mean by _"I need to create a couple (position, time)."_. What do you want the code to do that it's not already doing?

Comment: @Gianmarco: Define a `class Person:` with attributes `self.time`, `self.counter`, within the `after` loop decrement or increment the `.counter` and move if reached `0` or `.time`, reset and repeat.